# A Proof of sup(S + T) = sup(S) + sup(T).

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let S and T be nonempty bounded sets of real numbers and define
$S + T = \{s + t \;|\; s \in S, t \in T\}$.
Prove by using $\varepsilon$-language that
$\sup(S + T) = \sup(S) + \sup(T)$.
[image]

The picture is my method and I wonder if there are any logical mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing you forgot to check. The supremum of a set is its least upper bound. You only prove that *if* $\alpha + \beta$ is an upper bound of $S + T$, then $\alpha + \beta$ is the least upper bound. You still need to do one easy step: Check that any element of $S + T$ is less than $\alpha + \beta$. Then your proof is complete. Well done!

Comment: Thank you! I will complement it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, since supremum is a upper bound, we have
$s\leq \sup(S)$ for all $s\in S$ and $t\leq \sup(T)$ for all $t\in T$, then
$$s+t\leq\sup(S)+\sup(T) ,$$
that is
$$\sup (S+T)\leq\sup(S)+\sup(T).$$
On the other hand, by the definition of supremum, we have $\,\forall\, \epsilon>0$, there exists a $s_0\in S$ and $t_0\in T$ such that
$$\sup(S)-\epsilon/2<s_0\,\text{and}\,\sup(T)-\epsilon/2<t_0.$$
That is 
$$\sup(S)+\sup(T)-\epsilon<s_0+t_0\leq\sup(S+T).$$
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we get
$$\sup(S)+\sup(T)\leq\sup(S+T).$$
Hence
$$\sup(S)+\sup(T)=\sup(S+T).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it's more precise and detailed than mine.